# Adding Geometric Network Trace to Map Using ArcPy

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

I am able to run Geometric Network Trace by using following ArcPy script but I also need to add Trace result into the map. Can you please let me know how I can add the result(graphic/geometry) to the map.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:/Utility/Sample/Montgomery.gdb"
# Local variables:
G_N = "E:/Utility/Sample/Montgomery.gdb/Water/Water_Net"
Flag = "E:/Utility/Sample/Flag.shp"
traceOut = "traceOut_Net"

# Process: Trace Geometric Network
arcpy.TraceGeometricNetwork_management(G_N, traceOut, Flag, "TRACE_UPSTREAM", "", "", "", "", "", "NO_TRACE_ENDS", "", "", "", "AS_IS", "", "", "", "AS_IS")
print "Trace Done"
```

Comment: Cross posted on [GIS.SE] Stack Exchange - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240927/adding-geometric-network-trace-to-map-using-arcpy

Answer (score 0):

The [ArcPy mapping module](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/introduction-to-arcpy-mapping.htm) enables you to add layers to a map document (MXD).

Specifically, you want [`AddLayer`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/addlayer.htm) to add the layer to a given data frame. Since the output of [`TraceGeometricNetwork`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/trace-geometric-network.htm) appears to be a group layer, I believe it would work without additional manipulation; however, I've never worked with that specific tool.